# Node.js Mongoose nothing happens

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to connect to my mongodb database, but it doesn't work : it doesn't run the callback, and no error is thrown :

```
var config = require('./config');

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var schemas = require('./app/schemas');
var model = require('./app/model');
mongoose.connect(config.db_connection, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
});
var ModModel = mongoose.model('mods', schemas.modScheme);
var query = ModModel.find();
query.exec('find', function (err, mods) {
if (err) {
     throw err;
}
console.log('Retriveing mods...');
console.log(mods);
});
```

EDIT : This new code don't work

Here is the whole code : https://github.com/CraftYourModCorporation/RedstoneHub
(May not be complete, route getmods)

**Could someone link a project that uses mongoose please ?**

And output :

```
Important: use 'process.env.PORT' as the port and 'process.env.IP' as the host in your    scripts!
debugger listening on port 15400
Process terminated
```

Comment: Can you connect with the console?

Comment: In `var query = model.ModModel.find(null);` string you access `model` var, but never assigned it before.

Comment: And you're closing your connection before the `query.exec` callback has a chance to be called.

Comment: I changed it, and post, but it still not work

Comment: Based on your output including `Retriveing mods...`, it looks like the callback is being called.

Comment: I didn't update the new outpur until now. My github project with all the files : https://github.com/CraftYourModCorporation/RedstoneHub

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all of you, The problem was the connection string : instead of connecting using mongodb://user:pass@host/db, i had to use options. More details here : http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html